# Transforming Curl into Python using Urllib with Sentiment140 API

Tags: python, json, curl, urllib2, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to use Python to request data from the Sentiment140 API.
The API is using a Bulk Classification Service (JSON). Within terminal it is working fine

```
curl -d "{'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]}" http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson
```

leading to the following response:

```
{"data":[{"text":"I love Titanic.","polarity":4,"meta":{"language":"en"}},{"text":"I hate Titanic.","polarity":0,"meta":{"language":"en"}}]}
```

I thought I could just use urllib to get the same response from my python code. I tried:

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.sentiment140.com/api/bulkClassifyJson'
values = {'data': [{'text': 'I love Titanic.'}, {'text': 'I hate Titanic.'}]}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
page = response.read()
```

The code works but it does not give me any results.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use json here.

Try to do:

```
data = json.dumps(values) # instead of urllib.urlencode(values)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data)
page = response.read()
```

and on the top

```
import json
```